# Mongo authentication inside Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the mongo docker image with authentication. Following the most simple example from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mongo/#start-a-mongo-server-instance) I ran the mongo and the mongo-express images by the `docker-compose up` command. My `docker-compose.yml` at this stage:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

This runs, both containers start ok and I can browse the contents of mongo from the mongo-express website. However, whenever I change the username or the password in the `docker-compose.yml` file, for example to this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example123

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example123
```

the mongo-express throws an unauthotrized error message:

```
mongo-express_1  | Admin Database connected
mongo-express_1  | { MongoError: Authentication failed.
mongo-express_1  |     at Function.MongoError.create (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
mongo-express_1  |     at authenticateStragglers (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
mongo-express_1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:319:22)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
mongo-express_1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoError',
mongo-express_1  |   message: 'Authentication failed.',
mongo-express_1  |   ok: 0,
mongo-express_1  |   errmsg: 'Authentication failed.',
mongo-express_1  |   code: 18,
mongo-express_1  |   codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed' }
mongo-express_1  | unable to list databases
mongo-express_1  | { MongoError: command listDatabases requires authentication
mongo-express_1  |     at Function.MongoError.create (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
mongo-express_1  |     at authenticateStragglers (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
mongo-express_1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:319:22)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
mongo-express_1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoError',
mongo-express_1  |   message: 'command listDatabases requires authentication',
mongo-express_1  |   ok: 0,
mongo-express_1  |   errmsg: 'command listDatabases requires authentication',
mongo-express_1  |   code: 13,
mongo-express_1  |   codeName: 'Unauthorized' }
```

No matter what username or password I enter in `docker-compose.yml`, I cannot make mongo-express connect to mongo, only if I use the original `root` and `example` pair.

Note, that I am not getting the username and password as environment variables, but they are directly typed into the `docker-compose.yml` file as you can see here.

Also note, that when I change the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` (mongo's) variables to anything, they don't seem to have an effect, I can still connect with mongo-express using the original root and example credentials.

What causes this behaviour? How can I make this work?

Comment: My guess: INITDB variables are used only for initialization, so they won't be used if DB is already initialized. Try to destroy and then start your stack from the scratch and you will see.

Comment: I tried running `docker-compse up --build --force-recreate` which didn't solve this problem.

Comment: As a desperate attempt, I deleted all related containers and images. In this case I can use any username and password for the first time, so you are probably right about the INITDB variables, but I still don't know why exactly this happens.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your docker-compose command:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

Mongo image [uses anonymous volumes](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/6932ac255d29759af9a74c6931faeb02de0fe53e/4.0/Dockerfile#L87), so you need also `--renew-anon-volumes` ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)):

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --renew-anon-volumes
```

Otherwise previous volume with already initialized DB is used => INITDB env variables won't be used.

Comment: The `--renew-anon-volumes` flag solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 22):

What worked for me was just adding the environment variable for the mongodb server.

```
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
```

like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
```

Comment: This was it for me, been a while and seems the default host was removed at some point.

Comment: this is just crazy because in the mongo-express docker page it says the default is `mongo` but apparently it needs to be provided too

Comment: When `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER` is mongodb container name, not hostname.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to first stop all my containers.

Then `docker system prune -a --volumes`

**⚠️ This is the last resort.**  Before using this command check [the docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/),

Answer (score 2):

If you create the mongodb container (`docker-compose up` will build/pull the image and start a container) giving it the username and password, mongodb will configure itself on the first run and **never again**! Until you create a new container for that service, the default user/pass will be the ones set initially. If you want to change the default, a new container must be created.
You can also add users after the container has started.

Only stopping the service containers (`docker-compose stop`) will not destroy de container. To do so, call docker-compose down or, when starting, call `docker-compose up --force-recreate`.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `docker system prune -a --volumes` can solve the problem but a much simpler way is (if you are mounting a data volume for db to be persistent) to just delete and recreate a new one. This way other volumes will be untouched.
And of course combine it with : `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --renew-anon-volumes`