# mongodb runing on docker Failed to auth on robo 3t

Tags: laravel, mongodb, docker, authentication

i'am facing a probleme while trying to connect to my mongoDB with robo t3

My docker container connfiguration :

```
todo_mongodb:
  container_name: mongodb
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
  volumes:
      - "./mongo/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

Docker ps command show's :
[image]

i'am able to access mongodb shell and login as admin using

```
winpty docker exec -it mongodb bash
mongo admin -u admin -p admin
```

i've also tried to verify my admin db password using

```
    db.auth('admin','admin')
    > 1
```

i've tried to reset my containers but nothing **worked** any help please !!!

Comment: this is not related to laravel

Comment: @Thomas i'am building an app using docker laravel and mongodb
but thank you for complaining

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509236/mongo-authentication-inside-docker/53509958 : The --renew-anon-volumes flag

Comment: "but thank you for complaining" your question is not related to Laravel at all, your argument is invalid

Comment: include the error mate

Answer (score 0):

another instance of docker was running and blocking the connections ! hope this helps someone .